# Javabean jsp null

Tags: java, jsp, exception, null

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is with my jsp. I am getting `null` values when I am trying to print the values. Ask me any question if you're unsure.  I am using a bean.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="bean.BookingBean"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Output.jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Get Value from BookingBean</h1>


    <jsp:useBean id="formData" class="bean.BookingBean" scope ="session">

    </jsp:useBean>


    <TABLE BORDER=1>
        <tr><td>Receipt No: ....</td><td><jsp:getProperty name="formData" property="firstName" /> &nbsp <jsp:getProperty name="formData" property="surName"/></td>
            <td><jsp:getProperty name="formData" property="email" /></td>  
        </tr>

        <tr><td>Promotional Code: <jsp:getProperty name="formData" property="promo" /></td>
            <td><jsp:getProperty name="formData" property="date" /></td>
            <td><jsp:getProperty name="formData" property="location" /> &nbsp; <jsp:getProperty name="formData" property="time" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Adults:<jsp:getProperty name="formData" property="adult" /><br>
                Children's: <jsp:getProperty name="formData" property="children" /> <br>
                OAP: <jsp:getProperty name="formData" property="oap" /> </td>
            <TD COLSPAN=2><h3>Total Price: £......</h3></td>
        </tr>
    </table>





</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Could you post your BookingBean.java source code?

Comment: Do you have nulls in all cases? How do you sure your members do not actually have null values? Where do you initialize formData bean?

Answer (score 0):

include core taglib:
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

And try using (for each property):

```
<c:out value="${BookingBean.[PROPERTY_NAME]" />
```

First of all, check your getters and setters in BookingBean.java.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not using any indexed property in your bean class.
And check your getter setters in bean.